# Rails increment integer gives and error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I added points to users:

```
class AddPointsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :points, :integer, :default => 0
  end
end
```

And when I want to increment points in user controller on create action:
      `@user.update_attribute(:points, 100)`
or like this `@user.increment(:points, 100)`, I receive this error: `` ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `points`) ``

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

P.S. I ran rails db:migrate and have points in my schema. I still get the same error!

Comment: is it `users` many user or for a single `user`?

Comment: It seems like you forget to run your migration and I guess variable name should be @user. If it has many objects then it will generate error of undefined method or variable update_attribute in first place.

Comment: `@user.increment!(:points, 100)` try this.

Comment: @Manishh @Gabbar Sorry for typo in question but I actually used ```@user ``` not ```@users```, and it gave me an error. I just tried with ! and still the same error

Comment: can you check it on rails console whether its working  or not.

Comment: `@user.update_column(:points, 100)` optionally you can try this also.

Comment: @Gabbar, update_column does updates it but is there a way to increment with update_column since increment and update_attribute doesn't work?

Comment: it may be, but so far as i understand at the time of create the points value need to update instead of increment on existing points. anyway if i'll get your solution will let you know via answer. for now its solved your roadblock.

Comment: can you share your `create` action code?

Comment: @Gabbar ```def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.update_column(:points, 100)
      render json: status: 201
    else
      render json: status: 422
    end
    end```

Comment: why don't just add it in a before save callback

Comment: I am not sure why update_attribute doesn't work with integer since if works with other data types.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale @Gabbar I solved it. I added it before save callback and used ```@user.increment!(:points, 100)```. Thank you!

Comment: @KriloMax That's Great